# Getting statistics from sql

Tags: mysql

I would like to know if there is a way to make some sort of chart using info from a database. I have a table (Cars) with the following columns: id, type, price, color, brand, mileage, seller, views, and dateposted. I want to be able to create some stats for each item grouped by categories. For instance, let's say I have a sports black car with 99, 000 miles for $10, 000. I want to know how this specific black car ranks as compared to other black cars in my database based on price or views, mileage, price, etc.

Initially I thought I could do a bunch of separate queries. For instance, selecting min and max for a black car, and then combine them.

```
SELECT MIN(price) as lowest, MAX(price) as highest, price, color, brand, views FROM Shoes WHERE color='black' AND brand='honda' GROUP BY mileage;

SELECT MIN(price) as lowest, MAX(price) as highest, price, color, brand, views FROM Shoes WHERE color='black' AND brand='honda' GROUP BY price;
```

The above would give the min and max for a Honda black car based on the miles, the other would give me the min and max based on the price. Now, I can use this information to construct a bar chart. How could I do the same when I want to do it for different categories considering that my database is very large. Is there a way to optimize the performance?

Comment: 1. Optimise your indexes. 2. MySQL does not contain a chart implementation. You'll need to export the data into a usable format and generate charts using something else (such as Chart.js).

Comment: You have just described an OLAP cube. Unfortunately, MySQL does not have a native support for OLAP cubes, but there are quite a few tools out there that can either generate the reports from MySQL that you are looking for or can even build the cubes on the top of your database structure.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am aware that MYSQL does not have a chart implementation and I am using Chart.js. My question is with regards to minimizing traffic and/or the queries. I am not familiar with index optimization neither with OLAP cube. Could you point me in the direction to learn about indexing and some tools that could do that. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried googling the search expression "MySQL olap cube", or just simply "olap cube" (without speechmarks in both cases)? The search results will give you a good insight into this area.